# convex bounded, closed $\Longrightarrow$ compact?

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

I know that A subset S of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is compact if it is bounded and closed (Heire-Borel theorem),

Howver, if S is convex, containing the origin, closed, is it compact?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's compact _if and only if_ it's closed and bounded. Being convex or containing the origin has nothing to do with the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take $S=\mathbb{R}^n$, for instance. Or take any straight line passing through the origin.